# Best way to show exclusive forms?

Tags: forms, design-patterns

I have to develop a page with forms that are exclusive each other.

What is the best way or best practice to display mutually exclusive forms?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean 'different from each other' and not 'exclusive'. Other than that, we need a little more context. What forms are these and in what way are they different/exclusive?

Comment: we're going to need *a lot* more details here. What are your forms for? what have you tried? Who are the target users?

Comment: I think the question is misleading. Also, if you submit one form, does it direct you to another page? Is there any instance where you would want them to submit both of these forms or do you want to enforce they only interact with one?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use tabs (or radiobuttons styled as tabs in a web form) to toggle the two (or more) exclusive forms.